# Не открываются файлы через http сервер

Tags: javascript, http, сеть, веб-сервер

У меня есть файлы, которые находятся на сетевом диске. Я хочу работать с этими файлами через js, поэтому установил веб сервер и теперь просто открываю папку с файлами вот так:

```js
window.open('http://localhost/52_00/52_00_1/prc.txt')
```

Папка открывается нормально, а вот все файлы, лежащие внутри неё, просто грузятся и всё. Не каких ошибок не выдаётся, просто идёт загрузка страницы которая ни к чему не приводит. В инструментах разработчика в Network статус указан pending. Если открывать файлы с компа или вбить в адресную строку file://<адрес сервера>/52_00/52_00_1/, то файлы открываются нормально. Но я не могу работать через file:// потому что когда я пытаюсь открыть страницу таким способом через js

```js
window.open('file://<адрес сервера>/52_00/52_00_1/prc.txt');
```

из-за политик безопасности мне выдаётся ошибка: Not allowed to load local resource. Собственно именно из-за неё я и установил веб-сервер. Помогите пожалуйста с решением этой проблемы. Может есть другой способ открытия файлов на другом сетевом диске через сайт. Или может есть какие-то утилиты или программы, которые могут помочь в решении этой проблемы?